# Bootstrap dropdown button not working with version 3.3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to follow bootstrap button drop down , but not working.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Walter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Bunny</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Big Lewaoaski</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" >


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Components Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown" style="display: block;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown Example <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Walter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Bunny</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Big Lewaoaski</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You got a missing `>` on bootstrap-theme.min.css. Not sure if a typo though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the missing `>` if not a typo, you are not including the dropdown button to toggle the menu.

e.g.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Dropdown Example <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

So putting that on your current code:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="display: block;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown Example <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Walter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Bunny</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Big Lewaoaski</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ka62vqab/)**

Comment: Made the changes , still no toggle, Posting complete code on Edit

Comment: @Simsons Hmm that's weird. I tried it pasting your whole code to [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uZWCrQ9GNJ7b3a9flJbF?p=preview) and it also works. A stupid question but, is your index file located at desktop?

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan, No , It's not on desktop

Comment: You are right , it's working on plnkr, Not sure why not the local copy